# Why would I want to require a tty for sudo? What's the security benefit of requiring it?

Tags: security, virtual-machine, sudo, tty

I'm currently doing a project for my school aimed at creating a server in a VM.

One of the requirements of the subject was to install `sudo` on an emulated Debian Linux, with the following field in the `sudoers` config file:

```
Defaults        requiretty
```

The subject line requiring me to set this:

- The TTY mode has to be enabled for security reasons.

I know that `tty` is a command which prints the filename of a terminal that is currently connected to the standard input. However, what I can't see is how this ensures more security for the server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When `requiretty` is set, `sudo` must be run from a logged-in terminal session (a tty). This prevents `sudo` from being used from daemons or other detached processes like cronjobs or webserver plugins. It also means you can't run it directly from an `ssh` call without setting up a terminal session.

This can prevent certain kinds of escalation attacks. For example, if I have a way to modify the crontab for a user who has NOPASSWD sudo permissions, I could use that to kick off a job as root. With `requiretty`, I can't do that...

...easily. This restriction is not particularly hard to circumvent, and so generally isn't all that useful compared to the valid use cases it breaks. Red Hat used to use it, but [removed it](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1020147) a few years ago.

Comment: Thank you! I can roughly say that it's like a CAPTCHA on a website?

Comment: I don't think the mechanism is very comparable, but the goal, to "prove" a human rather than a script is driving it, is similar.